# Update to 13.10 without GUI access

Tags: command-line, upgrade, 13.10

After upgrading 13.04 with the latest patches, I'm getting some really weird problems -- namely, logging in at the GUI just dumps me back at the GUI login screen. I can, however, get command line access from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, and remotely via SSH.

Given that I was doing these updates to step to 13.10, I figure I might as well continue the process, and then deal with the fallout once I get there. However, how can this be achieved with **only the command line**, and no X available?

The only method I've found thus far is to run 'update-manager', which does not appear to have a CLI mode (and will not start without access to X).

What's the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

#### Note: you could be helped by this question: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

If you have access to CTRL+ALT+F1, this should be fine.

### If you're lucky, all you need to do is run `startx` once you're logged in and get to a usable (albeit compiz-less) desktop.

If you're less lucky, here's the long way:

I found instructions [here](http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line)

In a nutshell, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to update all packages, then

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

to do the actual update to 13.10

#### Otherwise,

Get your files out (using a Live USB/CD)
and reinstall from a 13.10 Live USB/CD.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can update from the command line. Use `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and your packages should be completely up to date. For a distribution upgrade do `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Nope - this doesn't switch from the 13.04 release to 13.10. It just tries to update to the latest packages *within* 13.04, which I've already done. (And caused listed problems!)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry i thought you wanted your packages updated. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo do-release-upgrade` from the command line.